# Proper way to call RTK Query endpoint.select() with no arguments (and skip options)

Tags: react-hooks, react-query, rtk-query

I would like to use the `endpoint.select()` function to create selectors from cached RTK Query data, see [RTK Advanced Patterns](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced).

The documentation clearly states that if there is no query argument, you can pass undefined to `select()` (see the **Selecting Users Data** section).

However, in my case this does not work unless i trigger the query by the **initiate()** function. When triggering the query from the query hook on the other hand, the selector fails to retrieve the cached data.

The **not working** setup here is pretty simple:

```
export const productsApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API.ENDPOINTS.PRODUCTS }),
  reducerPath: 'productsApi',
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    listAllProducts: builder.query({
      query: ()=>'/list',
    }),
  }),
});
export const { useListAllProductsQuery } = productsApi;
```

Then in a customHook I call the useListAllProducts hook:

```
const {
  data,
} = useListAllProductsQuery({skip:shouldSkip});
```

And finally in the selector:

```
export const selectProducts =
  productsApi.endpoints.listAllProducts.select(); //undefined param as docs recommend
```

**Potential Fix: (or more like a hacky workaround)**:
Strangely enough, I discovered that if i pass an argument (aka cacheKey) into the select function and pass that same cacheKey into the query hook, all of a sudden the stars align and everything works (although the docs state this is not necessary). So the modified code looks like:

```
// in selector
export const selectProducts =
  productsApi.endpoints.listAllProducts.select('products');

// in hook
const {
  data,
} = useListAllProductsQuery('products');
```

Im wondering if anyone can shed some wisdom on why this works, or even better can
recommend the best practice for utilizing the select function on a query with no cacheKey (since the docs seem incorrect or outdated?).

I would also like to point out, when calling `select()` without a parameter, a typescript warning surfaces indicating a parameter is required.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain where you think that the docs do state that you do not need an argument.

You will need to call `select` with **the same argument** as you call your hook **to get a selector for that cache key** - so if you call `useMyQuery()`, you can call `select()` - and if you call `useMyQuery(5)`, you can call `select(5)` to get a selector for the cache key `5`.

Those are individual cache entries and you will need a selector for each of those cache entries.

Also, could you clarify what exactly you mean by "not working"? Using the selector will give you only the cache entry, but not make a request - you are after all just selecting from the store. So before you used the hook or dispatched `initiate`, you will get an `uninitiated` cache entry.

Comment: The docs state it in multiple locations (specifically speaking of queries which dont have an argument). See the section that i cited "Selecting Users Data". In my example i do not have a cacheKey, so i'm simply calling select() which is not working. What i mean by not working is that the selector fails to return any data from the cache.

Comment: So in your example `useMyQuery()` needs to become `useMyQuery('someDummyKey') ` and select(`someDummyKey`). The moment i make this change, it works as expected.

Comment: If that is true, it would be a bug - but to be honest, it is highly unlikely, since `useMyQuery()` also just calls `select()` internally to get exactly that same selector. So I guess something else would be going on. Could you create a CodeSandbox which shows this behaviour?

Comment: Also, it seems very impossible that it does ever return nothing - it should at least return `{ status: "uninitialized", isUninitialized: true, is...: false }`

Comment: Good point, actually i just checked and it is returning `{status: 'uninitialized', isUninitialized: true, isLoading: false, isSuccess: false, isError: false}`. I was looking at the output of a dependent selector.

Comment: I see the problem, I was using UseQueryStateOptions to add skip logic, yet I believe this will cause issues when there is no key passed in. Ive updated to the following which seems to work now: `shouldSkip ? skipToken : undefined`

Comment: Options have to always be the second argument, so if you wanted to use `skip` instead of `skipToken`, you would have to call `useMyQuery(undefined, { skip: true })`. Using `undefined` as argument would work with a `select()` call, `undefined` and no arg are considered equal

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can solve your problem

in component.jsx file

```
const state = useSelector((state: RootState)=>state);
console.log(getState(state, params));
```

in api.js file

```
export const getState = (state: RootState, params) => api.endpoints.getApiState.select(params)(state);
```